# VBA Excel ?#NAME# error after insert function

Tags: excel, vba, function

After insert a function (SUMIF) with VBA in excel, I got a name error in those cells. However if I click and enter into a one of those cells, error is gone and functions is calculated correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

This is the VBA code:

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
With rst
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 1) = .Fields("Posting Date")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 2) = .Fields("Entry No_")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 3) = .Fields("G_L Account No_")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 4) = .Fields("Document No_")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 5) = .Fields("External Document No_")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 6) = "=customFunction(E" & line & ")"
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 7) = .Fields("Description")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 8) = .Fields("Debit Amount")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 9) = .Fields("Credit Amount")
    Sheets("Test").Cells(linea, 10) = .Fields("Amount")
    Sheets("Test").Range("K" & linea).Formula = "=SUMIF(F:F,F:F,J:J)"

    line = line + 1
    rst.MoveNext
End With
Loop
```

Comment: Why are using **linea** for the row number but incrementing **line = line + 1** ?

Comment: Typing error. That is line instead

Comment: You do know you can populate a range without looping right? For example put 1 in range A1:A10 and make B1 = A1 then run this in the debug window (ctrl-g in the VBE) `Range("B2:B10").Formula = "=B1+A2"` It auto increments without needed to loop through rows 2 to 10

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add:

Calculate

at the end of your VBA function to cause Excel to update the, err, calculations

Comment: Tried to calculate manually the sheet and at the end of my Sub but doesn't work. I thinks could be something about range names, but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was getting #name? error because I was using local function name. To solve this I used .FunctionLocal, this "translates" the Excel functions names if you are using a different language.

Thanks anyway.